# BST deleting root node with two children

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I coded case #2 in delete_node but am getting a segmentation error. I'm using the predecessor to delete the node. I'm not sure what happens when I am removing the root node with two children. Is it the same as deleting a non-root node with two children except you don't have to connect the predecessor's children? I think that's how I've coded it...

```
bool delete_node(Node*& root, KType key) {

// find target node to delete
Node* target = find(key, root);
if (!target) return false;

// find parent of target
Node* parent = find_parent(root, target);

// case 1: target is a leaf
if (target->left == NULL && target->right == NULL) {
    // set parent's child pointer
    if (parent != NULL) {
        if ( parent->left == target )
            parent->left = NULL;
        else
            parent->right = NULL;
    }
    else
        root = NULL;

    // free target
    delete target;
    return true;
}

// case 2: target has two children
else if (target->left != NULL && target->right != NULL) {
    if (parent != NULL) {
        //find predecessor
        Node* temp = target->left;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            temp = temp->right;
        }

        // find predecessor's parent
        Node* predecessorParent = find_parent(root, temp);

        target->key = temp->key;

        if (predecessorParent->left == temp) {
            predecessorParent->left = temp->left;
        } else {
            predecessorParent->right = temp->left;
        }

        delete(temp);
        return true; // return true when you're done.
    } else {
        //find predecessor
        Node* temp = target->left;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            temp = temp->right;
        }
        target->key = temp->key;
        delete(temp);
        return true; // return true when you're done.
    }
}


// case 3: target has only left child
else if (target->left != NULL) {
    // set parent's child pointer
    if (parent != NULL) {
        if ( parent->left == target )
            parent->left = target->left;
        else
            parent->right = target->left;
    }
    else
        root = target->left;

    // free target
    delete target;
    return true;
}

// case 4: target has only right child
else {
    // set parent's child pointer
    if (parent != NULL) {
        if (parent->left == target)
            parent->left = target->right;
        else
            parent->right = target->right;
    }
    else
        root = target->right;

    // free target
    delete target;
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

find_parent function:

```
/**
 * Finds the parent of node in the tree rooted at rootNode
 */
Node* find_parent(Node* rootNode, Node* node) {
    if ( rootNode == NULL || rootNode == node ) {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if ( rootNode->left == node || rootNode->right == node ) {
        return rootNode;
    }
    else if (node->key < rootNode->key) {
        return find_parent(rootNode->left, node);
    }
else {
    return find_parent(rootNode->right, node);
    }
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong...I'm still looking around...  But doesn't the While loop at the top of your Case 2 always produce temp = NULL?  You have a while loop that produces temp = NULL, and then you pass temp to the find_parent function.  I'm guessing you get your segfault in the find_parent function -- yes?  Also, I'm trying to understand what you plan to do with the children...   Your node has 1 parent (lets say parent->right points to target) which may already have parent->left defined.  How will you map 2 children from the target to parent with only 1 pointer left?

Comment: If you delete a node (root node or otherwise) that has 2 children, each child then becomes the root node of a new tree.  There won't be any nodes in the original tree that point to any nodes in the 2 new trees.